# Java, Android : Jetty scheduler method throwing NPE, don't know where it's getting called

Tags: java, android, jetty, cometd

I am working on an Android application in which I am trying to initialize a LongPollingTransport as mentioned below. But I am getting an error from Jetty scheduler. I am not calling the Jetty Scheduler class myself. How can I fix this. Any help would be nice.

Code :

```
public class ConsoleChatClient {


    private volatile String nickname = "kernel";
    private volatile BayeuxClient client;
    private final ChatListener chatListener = new ChatListener();
    private final MembersListener membersListener = new MembersListener();
    HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();

    public void run() throws IOException
    {


        String defaultURL = "http://localhost:8080/cometd/cometd";

        client = new BayeuxClient(defaultURL, new LongPollingTransport(null,httpClient));
        client.getChannel(Channel.META_HANDSHAKE).addListener(new InitializerListener());
        client.getChannel(Channel.META_CONNECT).addListener(new ConnectionListener());
//Line below throws an error
-->        client.handshake(); 
}
```

Error log :

```
11-12 10:56:38.317 19972-19972/internetlegion.twentynotes E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{internetlegion.twentynotes/internetlegion.twentynotes.Login.LoginActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.Scheduler$Task org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.Scheduler.schedule(java.lang.Runnable, long, java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)' on a null object reference
11-12 10:56:38.317 19972-19972/internetlegion.twentynotes E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2411)
11-12 10:56:38.317 19972-19972/internetlegion.twentynotes E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2474)
11-12 10:56:38.317 19972-19972/internetlegion.twentynotes E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
11-12 10:56:38.317 19972-19972/internetlegion.twentynotes E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1359)
11-12 10:56:38.317 19972-19972/internetlegion.twentynotes E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-12 10:56:38.317 19972-19972/internetlegion.twentynotes E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
11-12 10:56:38.317 19972-19972/internetlegion.twentynotes E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5696)
11-12 10:56:38.317 19972-19972/internetlegion.twentynotes E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
11-12 10:56:38.317 19972-19972/internetlegion.twentynotes E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
11-12 10:56:38.317 19972-19972/internetlegion.twentynotes E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1028)
11-12 10:56:38.317 19972-19972/internetlegion.twentynotes E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823)
11-12 10:56:38.317 19972-19972/internetlegion.twentynotes E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.Scheduler$Task org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.Scheduler.schedule(java.lang.Runnable, long, java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)' on a null object reference
11-12 10:56:38.317 19972-19972/internetlegion.twentynotes E/AndroidRuntime:     at org.eclipse.jetty.client.TimeoutCompleteListener.schedule(TimeoutCompleteListener.java:53)
11-12 10:56:38.317 19972-19972/internetlegion.twentynotes E/AndroidRuntime:     at org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpRequest.send(HttpRequest.java:675)
11-12 10:56:38.317 19972-19972/internetlegion.twentynotes E/AndroidRuntime:     at org.cometd.client.transport.LongPollingTransport.send(LongPollingTransport.java:187)
11-12 10:56:38.317 19972-19972/internetlegion.twentynotes E/AndroidRuntime:     at org.cometd.client.BayeuxClient$BayeuxClientState.transportSend(BayeuxClient.java:1430)
11-12 10:56:38.317 19972-19972/internetlegion.twentynotes E/AndroidRuntime:     at org.cometd.client.BayeuxClient$BayeuxClientState.send(BayeuxClient.java:1425)
11-12 10:56:38.317 19972-19972/internetlegion.twentynotes E/AndroidRuntime:     at org.cometd.client.BayeuxClient.sendHandshake(BayeuxClient.java:403)
11-12 10:56:38.317 19972-19972/internetlegion.twentynotes E/AndroidRuntime:     at org.cometd.client.BayeuxClient$HandshakingState.execute(BayeuxClient.java:1526)
11-12 10:56:38.317 19972-19972/internetlegion.twentynotes E/AndroidRuntime:     at org.cometd.client.BayeuxClient.changeState(BayeuxClient.java:1082)
11-12 10:56:38.317 19972-19972/internetlegion.twentynotes E/AndroidRuntime:     at org.cometd.client.BayeuxClient.handshake(BayeuxClient.java:339)
11-12 10:56:38.317 19972-19972/internetlegion.twentynotes E/AndroidRuntime:     at org.cometd.client.BayeuxClient.handshake(BayeuxClient.java:315)
11-12 10:56:38.317 19972-19972/internetlegion.twentynotes E/AndroidRuntime:     at internetlegion.twentynotes.Activity.ConsoleChatClient.run(ConsoleChatClient.java:38)
11-12 10:56:38.317 19972-19972/internetlegion.twentynotes E/AndroidRuntime:     at internetlegion.twentynotes.Login.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:66)
11-12 10:56:38.317 19972-19972/internetlegion.twentynotes E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5958)
11-12 10:56:38.317 19972-19972/internetlegion.twentynotes E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1129)
11-12 10:56:38.317 19972-19972/internetlegion.twentynotes E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2364)
11-12 10:56:38.317 19972-19972/internetlegion.twentynotes E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2474) 
11-12 10:56:38.317 19972-19972/internetlegion.twentynotes E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144) 
11-12 10:56:38.317 19972-19972/internetlegion.twentynotes E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1359) 
11-12 10:56:38.317 19972-19972/internetlegion.twentynotes E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
11-12 10:56:38.317 19972-19972/internetlegion.twentynotes E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155) 
11-12 10:56:38.317 19972-19972/internetlegion.twentynotes E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5696) 
11-12 10:56:38.317 19972-19972/internetlegion.twentynotes E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
11-12 10:56:38.317 19972-19972/internetlegion.twentynotes E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
11-12 10:56:38.317 19972-19972/internetlegion.twentynotes E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1028) 
11-12 10:56:38.317 19972-19972/internetlegion.twentynotes E/AndroidR
```

Build.gradle (For app)

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.6.0'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.6.0'
    compile 'org.springframework.android:spring-android-rest-template:1.0.1.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework.android:spring-android-core:1.0.1.RELEASE'
    compile('org.springframework.android:spring-android-auth:1.0.1.RELEASE') {
        exclude group: 'org.springframework', module: 'commons-logging'
        exclude group: 'org.springframework', module: 'spring-core'
        exclude group: 'org.springframework', module: 'spring-web'
    }
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.6.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
    compile 'com.tonicartos:superslim:0.4.13'
    compile 'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.9'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'org.cometd.java:bayeux-api:3.0.6'
    compile 'org.cometd.java:cometd-java-server:3.0.6'
    compile 'org.cometd.java:cometd-java-client:3.0.6'
    compile 'org.cometd.java:cometd-java-annotations:3.0.6'
}
```

Any help would be nice. Thanks a lot. :-)

*Edit*

Finally I debugged it and found that HandshakeState.toString is throwing an NPE, but as this is a library method, I have no idea what to do about it.

Error :

```
Method threw 'java.lang.NullPointerException' exception. Cannot evaluate org.cometd.client.BayeuxClient$HandshakingState.toString()
```

Failing method :

```
   private class HandshakingState extends BayeuxClientState
    {

--->        private HandshakingState(Map<String, Object> handshakeFields, ClientSessionChannel.MessageListener callback, ClientTransport transport)
        {
            super(State.HANDSHAKING, handshakeFields, callback, null, transport, null, 0);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I doubt `HandshakingState.toString()` throws an `NullPointerException`, since the only thing `toString()` does is to forward the call to the enum `type` field.

What seems to me from your code is that the `HttpClient` is not started.

The `HttpClient` instance is created as a field in class `ConsoleChatClient`, but you never call `start()` on it.

This is important because you can have multiple `BayeuxClient` instances referring to the same `HttpClient` instance, so the lifecycle of `HttpClient` must be started before you are using `BayeuxClient`.

Comment: I agree with you, this code does not have httpclient started, and i noticed one with start, so i tried it after starting the client as well. And the error log is copied directly from debugger.

Comment: Any thoughts you have?

Comment: I don't understand ? Start the HttpClient and the problem will go away. If it does not, then you need to provide more information. I doubt you will get the same error if HttpClient is started.

Comment: Your original question reports an Android error log that shows a `NullPointerException` caused by the `HttpClient` not being started. Post another log that shows the actual code that you are running, and the actual log that you get. Because you are not really asking a question, but you are asking for help to troubleshoot your problems, it's probably better for you to join the [CometD mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/cometd-users) and ask these (multiple) questions there.

Comment: I just added httpClient.start() and I got the same error at client.hanshake();  But you are right, the question seems mixed up. My work is almost over for today, I will post the complete error log tomorrow with stacktrace as well as debug log when httpClient is already started. I also received your email, and once this error is gone, I can then use Cometd more properly and will surely write a tutorial. Thanks a lot... :-)